# Unspecified error (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004005(E_FAIL)) (Web Service)

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, visual-studio-2013, windows-7-x64

I get the following error when I try to make a new Web Service Application (using ASP.NET)

[image: Error Message]

I only get it when I try to make a Web Service.

I tried removing IIS Express and installing it again. I tried starting devenv.exe with /SafeMode and /ResetSettings but to no avail. I get the same error every time.

I am using VS2013 Premium and Windows 7 x64. Anyone got any other solutions?

Comment: @Crowcoder Why would you even say that, when I specifically need to use web services? Do you just like to watch the world burn or?

Comment: How would I know you MUST use web services? You mention a new project which is normally a good opportunity to change direction. Otherwise, you provide too little information to help you.

Comment: @Crowcoder I said I only get the error when I make a web service. Then you say "Don't try to solve the issue at hand. Just avoid it entirely and use some other technology that's not part of your tags!" That's not being helpful in the slightest.

Answer (score -2):

Please try to do the following steps:

-Inside the IIS Manager administration tool, right-click on virtual directory "ControllerHelp" and choose "Manage Virtual Directory - Advanced Settings"

-Inside the section 'Physical Path Credentials' modify the user/password to the correct values, or choose the default ("Application user (pass-through authentication)").

if it is not working, please try to repair the installed version of visual studio

Comment: [The first Google hit](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21450252) doesn't always apply. Answers are not the place for guessing. First you need to understand the actual source of the error, then solutions can be posted.

Answer (score -2):

Open your Visual stdio "RUN as Administrator". 
Any visual stdio 2013 2015 2017 will not throw this error if run as administrator.